# Swagger Example Parameter Value

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-ui

I want to modify the Example Value under the Data Type on my Swagger-ui interface. currently it contains the following default value (generated by Swagger):

```
"user":{
        "birth":null,
        "nationality":null,
        "lastname":null,
        "firstname":null,
        "identity":null
     }
```

I want to specify real values instead of the "null" values.
PS: I use spring boot with annotations: @ApiOperation,...

Comment: Do you mean something like `@ApiParam`? http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiParam.html

Comment: When I use the @ApiParam(value="...")  I find my example under the description which is not what I want (every other property of @ApiParam shwos nothing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must then insert @ApiModelProperty anotation for all your attributes inside your bean. Then put an example attribute inside. Let's say your user is mapped to the User.java class, so you would have:

```
public class User {

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "The birthdate", example = "1985-12-07", format= "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private String birth;
```

Comment: what if i want to add a list of examples ??

Comment: @dzgeek have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40989038/swagger-apimodelproperty-example-value-for-liststring-property

Comment: thank you, but i meant multiple examples for the same entity, not example of a list container,